# swift with syntax on method parameters

Tags: swift, parameters, function-parameter

I've seen this syntax in code examples and blogs, but have not seen it explained:

```
func exampleFunc(arg1: String, withOtherArgument otherArgument: String) -> Void {}
```

What does the with syntax do? Why is it necessary, and how is it different from just:

```
func exampleFunc(arg1: String, otherArgument: String) -> Void {}
```

Comment: It's fully explained in the Swift book. See the [Function Argument Labels and Parameter Names](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID158) section in the Functions chapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Apple’s [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID166) says:

> Each function parameter has both an argument label and a parameter
>   name. The argument label is used when calling the function; each
>   argument is written in the function call with its argument label
>   before it. The parameter name is used in the implementation of the
>   function. By default, parameters use their parameter name as their
>   argument label.

In your first example `withOtherArgument` is the argument label and the `otherArgument` is the parameter name.